# JQUERY function is sending data multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to update user's profile in my website and it will send data to a webpage. But problem is that it is sending data multiple times. I am not using any onclick function or like that. My jquery ajax codes are,

```
        success:function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(json.error == 'false')
                {
                    $('#result').html('Working <img src="/imgs/loading.GIF"/><br>'+json.message);
                    updateProfilePic(uname);
                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#result').html('Working <img src="/imgs/loading.GIF"/><br><b>Error</b> : '+json.message).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }
```

"updateProfilePic(uname)" is the other ajax function that I am calling to post profile picture details. So if my json response is getting error false then it will send profile image. First, I am updating user details and then profile picture. So basically this process is happening in two different functions.

I don't want my **updateProfilePic** to run multiple times so is there any option that I can use? I know how to use **.bind()** with click function but I don't want user to click on any button or link so how can I stop my function to send data multiple times?

Here is the whole updateProfilePic function

```
function updateProfilePic(uname){
        var imgU = $('#upic').val();
        var img  = $('#usrProPic').attr('src');
        var updater = ''

        if(img == '/imgs/male.png' || img == '/imgs/female.png'){
            updater = 'system';
            imgU = img;
        }else{
            updater = 'user';
        }

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType : 'HTML',
            url:"/ajax/update/userpropic",
            data: {
                    staimg: 'true',
                    u: uname,
                    i: imgU,
                    updater: updater
                },
            success:function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(json.error == 'false')
                {
                    $('#result').html('Working <img src="/imgs/loading.GIF"/><br>'+json.message);
                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#result').html('Working <img src="/imgs/loading.GIF"/><br><b>Error</b> : '+json.message).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How is the first piece of code called?

Comment: The first piece was called by bind('click') function. $('#updpr').bind('click',function(){
          updateProfileDetails(fname, lname, country, state, city, gndr, uname);
         });

Comment: is `updateProfileDetails()` called more than once as well? How do you know that `updateProfilePic()` is called multiple times? Could you try to trim your code until you can isolate the problem?

Comment: I was alerting something in this function and that is how I know.